# jQuery UI Tabs, how to solve TypeError: ui.jqXHR.error is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the latest version jQuery UI for tabs but i get the following error in

> TypeError: ui.jqXHR.error is not a function

Here is my actual code that manages tabs

```
$(function() {
        $( diaise_et_id ).tabs({

            beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
                ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                    ui.panel.html(
                        "Couldn't load this tab. Please check your internet connection or connection to the server. " +
                        "Praise God forever More" );
                });
            }
        });
```

And this is how i call the function

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
pour_les_tabs("#tabs_20");
</script>
```

I am still seeing

> TypeError: ui.jqXHR.error is not a function.

**What could probably be the problem and how to solve it please ?**

Thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ `Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.` Possibly relevant for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object provides a subset of following methods 
`then`, `done`, `fail`, `always`, `pipe`, `progress`, `state` and `promise`

So use fail in place of error:

```
ui.jqXHR.fail(function (e) {
    // We have failed to load the tab content
});
```

Comment: You made my day. Thank you very much